# How to add a smart button in sales module in Odoo12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to add a smart button on sales module in Odoo 12, when i click on it,it displays the overdue invoices of that customer

i have already tried to do it by inheriting the sales module but its not working

Answer (score 0):

First you need to inherit partner view and add the smart button:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_view_buttons">
        <field name="name">partner.view.buttons</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <div name="button_box" position="inside">
                <button type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-pencil-square-o" name="action_view_partner_overdue_invoices"
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('customer', '=', False)]}" context="{'default_partner_id': active_id}">
                    <div class="o_form_field o_stat_info">
                        <span class="o_stat_value">
                            <field name="total_overdue" widget='monetary' options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="o_stat_text">Total Overdue</span>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
          </field>
        </record>
```

Inherit `res.partner` model and add `action_view_partner_overdue_invoices` method which returns an [action with domain](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/partner.py#L437) to filter invoices

Add a computed field `total_overdue` to show the total overdue.

Comment: but i want to show this button on sales order form,,,,

Comment: and when i click on it,,,it should display those invoices of that customer,,,,that are overdue

Comment: Did you write a method to get those overdue invoices?

Comment: its alrit,,,i have succeded in it,,,thanks for your time anyways

Comment: Feel free to vote up or accept any of those answers if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The code below calculates the number of invoices for a customer and to display its billing list, it can help you to display the smart button and test your function:

### **In XML:**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_view_buttons">
    <field name="name">partner.view.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <div name="button_box" position="inside">

             <button name="act_show_invoice" type="object" icon="fa-usd" class="oe_stat_button"
                help="courriel">
                <field name="invoice_count" widget="statinfo"/>
             </button>

            </div>

    </field>
</record>
```

### **In python:**

```
invoice_count = fields.Integer(string='Nbr Facture', compute='_compute_invoice_count',)
```

### The compute method to get the count

```
def _compute_invoice_count(self):
    invoice_data = self.env['account.invoice'].read_group(domain=[('partner_id', 
                'child_of', self.ids)],fields=['partner_id'], groupby=['partner_id'])
    partner_child_ids = self.read(['child_ids'])
    mapped_data = dict([(m['partner_id'][0], m['partner_id_count']) for m in 
                                                                     invoice_data])
    for partner in self:
        # let's obtain the partner id and all its child ids from the read up there
        item = next(p for p in partner_child_ids if p['id'] == partner.id)
        partner_ids = [partner.id] + item.get('child_ids')
        # then we can sum for all the partner's child
        partner.invoice_count = sum(mapped_data.get(child, 0) for child in 
        partner_ids)
```

### For the Navigation to the tree view or related records

```
 def act_show_invoice(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    res = self.env['ir.actions.act_window'].for_xml_id(
        'account', 'action_invoice_tree1')
    res.update(
        context=dict(
            self.env.context,
            search_default_partner_id=self.id,
        ),
    )

    return res
```

i hope it can help you